# Why does JLS state that the largest int literal is 2147483648?

Tags: java, jls

JLS `3.10.1. Integer Literals` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1 states

```
The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648.
```

At the same time this line

```
int x = 2147483648;
```

produces a compile error

```
The literal 2147483648 of type int is out of range
```

Is JLS wrong?

Comment: "The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (231).

All decimal literals from 0 to 2147483647 may appear anywhere an int literal may appear.

It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (231), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator (§15.15.4)."

Comment: I agree though that it's confusing. The wording could be a lot better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (231).

```
All decimal literals from 0 to 2147483647 may appear anywhere an int literal may appear.
```

It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (231), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator [(§15.15.4).](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4)

Answer (score 6):

It is poorly worded IMHO. What it's trying to say us that in this expression:

```
-2147483648
```

The minus sign is *not* part of the integer literal, rather the minus sign is the *unary minus operator* and `2147483648` is the `int` literal, and integer literal `2147483648` may only appear in this exact expression.

Answer (score 5):

> Is JLS wrong?

No, the JLS is being specific - differentiate between an int variable and an "int literal", i.e. decimal literal of type int.

The range of an *int variable* is -2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647 (i.e. -(2^31)..2^31-1)

The largest *decimal literal* the compiler will parse in Java code and use in an `int` context is 2,147,483,648, but it can only be used as the operand of the unary '-' operator, that is to say, you can only use it in only one way - to construct the most negative decimal value an int can hold: `-22147483648`.

In that section of the JLS you mention, [section 3.10.1 Integer Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1%5D), where it says:

> The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (2^31).

is also says a few lines later:

> It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2^31), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator.